Flutter - Android project github package dependency not resolving
I have published a private repo on github packages which i am successfully able to use in one of the Android native project but while trying to do the same in the Android module in flutter project gradle is not able to resolve the dependency.
getting below error.
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.example:my-artifactId:1.0.0-beta5.
     Searched in the following locations:

       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/orgname/my-artifactId/1.0.0-beta5/my-artifactId-1.0.0-beta5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/orgname/my-artifactId/1.0.0-beta5/my-artifactId-1.0.0-beta5.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/orgname/my-artifactId/1.0.0-beta5/my-artifactId-1.0.0-beta5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :my_project

Android build.gradle file is configured like below
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.8.22"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/orgname/repo")
            credentials {
                username = "my_username"
                password = "my_token"
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/orgname/repo")
            credentials {
                username = "my_username"
                password = "my_token"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
        implementation("groupId:my-artifactId:1.0.0-beta5")
    }

published like below
publishing {
publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("gpr") {
        groupId = "groupId"
        artifactId = "my-artifactId"
        version = "1.0.0-beta5"

        afterEvaluate {
            from(components["release"])
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        name = "GitHubPackages"
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/orgname/repo")
        credentials {
            username = "$user"
            password = "$token"
        }
    }
}

}
look like gradle is not trying to resolve it from the githubPackages maven repo.

I figured out the issue, maven{} custome url block needed to be added to apps build.gradle file too along with project build.gradle file.
